# Can I replace an STM32F105-RBT6 with a STM32F103-RET6? (ie. are they pin compatible?)

Tags: stm32, stm32f103

I'm using a Gotek Floppy Emulator which uses an STM32F105-RBT6.  However, the chip appears to have died and I have a STM32F103-RET6 on-hand.  They are both LQFP packages but are they pin compatible?

How likely can I replace the chip and re-flash the same firmware?

Comment: what did the documentation indicate about pinout?

Comment: If they are pin compatible, then what? Then you also need to know if they are software compatible too, or you can't use the same binary. What does the Gotek documentation say which MCUs can be used?

Answer (score 13):

STM32F10**5** series have *OTG_FS* USB hardware which allows them to be USB host devices. It seems like *Gotek Floppy Emulator* uses this feature. STM32F10**3** series on the other hand, have a completely different USB hardware, called *FS Device* and it can't act as an USB host.

You don't need to look any further. They are not compatible.

Answer (score 9):

To answer your question, yes, the F103 and F105 MCUs are pin-compatible hardware-wise. That's what you asked in the topic.

But the devices are not compatible peripheral-wise and software-wise.

So no, you can't use an F103 in an application that requires an F105 peripherals and features.

The firmware binary that uses F105 peripherals and features cannot run on F103.